# moving from for() to map() - can't get my head around it

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming

Wondering if someone can help - I'm wanting to use `Array.map` and `Array.filter` but i'm so stuck in my `for` loop thinking that despite reading tutorials etc i can't seem to get my head around this.

In this code, I have an `Array` of objects, I want to:

1. compare each item in the array with the other items, and ensure that `obj[i] != obj[i]`
2. perform operations on current item: check if `item.target` is `null`, compare `distance` between `item` and `item+1`, and if `item` & `item+1` `distance` is smaller than `item` & `item.target` then i want to replace `item.target` with `item`.

code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 111; i++) {
  var itm = {x:Math.random()*w, y:Math.random()*h, tgt:null};
  dotArr.push(itm);
}
function findTarget(itemA, itemB){ 
  var x1 = itemA.x; 
  var y1 = itemA.y; 
  var x2 = itemB.x; 
  var y2 = itemB.y; 
  var distance = Math.sqrt( (x2-=x1)*x2 + (y2-=y1)*y2 ); 
  return distance; 
}

for (var i = 0; i < dotArr.length; i++) {
  let itm = dotArr[i];
  for (var j = 0; j < dotArr.length; j++) {
    if(itm != dotArr[j]){
      let itm2 = this.dotArr[j];
      if(itm.tgt==null){
        itm.tgt = itm2;
      }else{
        let newDist = findTarget(itm, itm2);
        let curDist = findTarget(itm, itm.tgt);
        if(newDist<curDist){
          itm.tgt = itm2;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

All the 'multiply each value by 2' examples in the tutorials i read make sense but can't extrapolate that into an approach that i use all the time.

Expected results: i have a bunch of particles, they are looping through a requestAnimationFrame() loop, checking the distance each loop. Each particle finds the closest particle and sets it to 'tgt' (and then moves toward it in other code), but it updates each loop.

Comment: Edit your original post instead of putting it in the comment section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Summary

```
const distance = (a, b) => 
  Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b.x - a.x, 2) + Math.pow(b.y - a.y, 2))

const findClosest = (test, particles) => particles.reduce(
  ({val, dist}, particle) => {
    const d = distance(test, particle)
    return d < dist && d != 0 ? {val: particle, dist: d} : {val, dist}
  },
  {val: null, dist: Infinity}
).val

const addTargets = particles => particles.map(particle => {
  particle.tgt = findClosest(particle, particles)
  return particle
})
```

(This is hard to do in a snippet because of the cyclic nature of your data structure.  JSON stringification doesn't work well with cycles.)

### Change style for the right reason

You say you want to change from `for`-loops to `map`, `filter`, *et. al.*, but you don't say **why**.  Make sure you're doing this for appropriate reasons.  I am a strong advocate of functional programming, and I generally push junior developers I'm responsible for to make such changes.  But I explain the reasons.

Here is the sort of explanation I make:

> "When you're doing a loop, you're doing it for a *reason*.  If you are looking to transform a list of values one-by-one into another list of values, then there is a built-in called `map` which makes your code clearer and simpler.  When you're trying to check for those which should be kept, then you have `filter`, which makes your code clearer and simpler.  When you want to find the first item in a list with a certain property, you have `find`, which, again, is clearer and simpler.  And if you are trying to combine the elements until you're reduced them to a single value, you can use `reduce`, which, surprise, surprise, is cleaner and simpler.
>
> "The reason to use these is to better express the *intent* of your code.  Your intent is pretty well never going to be 'to continually increment the value of some counter starting with some value and ending when some condition is met, performing some routine on each iteration.'  If you can use tools that better express your goals, then your code is easier to understand.  So look for where `map`, `filter`, `find`, and `reduce` make sense in your code.
>
> "Not every `for`-loop fits one of these patterns, but a large subset of them will.  Replacing those that do fit will make for more understandable, and therefore more maintainable, code."

I will go on from there to explain the advantages of never worrying about fencepost errors and how some of these functions can work with more generic types, making it easier to reuse such code.  But this is the basic gist I use with my teams.

You need to decide *why* you're changing, and if it makes sense in your case.  There is a real possibility, given your requirements, that it doesn't.

The functions `map`, `find`, and `filter` work only on individual items in your list.  `reduce` works on one item and the currently accumulated value.  It looks as though your requirement is to word pair-wise across all the values.  That might mean that none of these functions is a good fit.

Or perhaps they do.  Read on for how I would solve this.

### Names are important

You include a function called `findTarget`.  I would assume that such a function somehow or another finds a target.  In fact, all it does it to calculate the distance between two items.

Imagine coming to someone else's code and reading through the code that uses `findTarget`.  Until you read that function, you will have no idea that it's simply calculating a distance.  The code will seem strange.  It will be much harder to understand than if you just named it `distance`.

Also, using `item` or the shortened version `itm` does not tell the reader anything about what these are.  (**Update**: a change to the post points out that these are 'particles', so I will use that rather than `itm` in the code.)

### Avoid trickiness

That `findTarget`/`distance` function does something strange, and somewhat difficult to follow.  It modifies computation variables in the middle of the computation: `(x2-=x1)*x2` and `(y2-=y1)*y2`.  While I can see that this works out the same, it's easy to write a very clear distance function without this trickiness:

```
const distance = (a, b) => 
    Math.sqrt((b.x - a.x) * (b.x - a.x) + (b.y - a.y) * (b.y - a.y))
```

There are many variants of this that are just as clear.

```
const distance = (a, b) =>
    Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b.x - a.x, 2) + Math.pow(b.y - a.y, 2))
```

And one day we'll be able to do

```
const distance = (a, b) => Math.sqrt((b.x - a.x) ** 2 + (b.y - a.y) ** 2)
```

Any of these would make for much clearer code.  You could also use intermediate variables such as `dx`/`dy` or `deltaX`/`deltaY` if that made it clearer to you.

### Look carefully at your requirements

It took me far too long looking at your code to determine what precisely you were trying to do.

If you can break apart the pieces you need into named functions, it's often significantly easier to write, and it's generally much easier for someone else to understand (or even for yourself a few weeks later.)

So, if I understand the problem correctly now, you have a list of positioned objects, and for each one of them you want to update them with a target, that being the object closest to them.  That sounds very much like `map`.

Given that, I think the code should look something like:

```
const addTargets = particles => particles.map(item => ({
    x: item.x,
    y: item.y,
    tgt: findClosest(item, particles)
}))
```

Now I don't know how `findClosest` will work yet, but I expect that this matches the goal if only I could write that.

Note that this version takes seriously my belief in the functional programming concept of immutability.  But it won't quite do what you want, because a particle's target will be the one from the old list and not one from its own list.  I personally might look at altering the data structure to fix this.  But instead, let's ease that restriction and rather than returning new items, we can update items in place.

```
const addTargets = particles => particles.map(particle => {
    particle.tgt = findClosest(particle, particles)
    return particle
})
```

So notice what we're doing here: we're turning a list of items without targets (or with `null` ones) into a list of items with them.  But we break this into two parts: one converts the elements without the targets to ones with them; the second finds the appropriate target for a given element.  This more clearly captures the requirements.

We still have to figure out how to find the appropriate target for an element.  In the abstract, what we're doing is to take a list of elements and turning it into a single one.  That's `reduce`.  (This is not a `find` operation, since it has to check everything in the list.)

Let's write that, then:

```
const findClosest = (test, particles) => particles.reduce(
  ({val, dist}, particle) => {
    const d = distance(test, particle)
    return d < dist && d != 0 ? {val: particle, dist: d} : {val, dist}
  },
  {val: null, dist: Infinity}
).val
```

We use the distance for dual purposes here.  First, of course, we're looking at how far apart two particles are.  But second, we assume that another particle in the same exact location is the same particle.  If that is not accurate, you'll have to alter this a bit.

At each iteration, we have a new object with `val` and `dist` properties.  And this always represents the closest particle we've found so far and its distance from our current particle.  At the end, we just return the `val` property.  (The reaon for `Infinity` is that *every* particle will be closer than that, so we don't need specific logic to test the first one.)

### Conclusion

In the end we were able to use `map` and `reduce`.  Note that in this example we have two reusable helper functions, but each is used just once.  If you don't need to reuse them, you could fold them into the functions that call them.  But I would not recommend it.  This code is fairly readable.  Folded in, these would be less expressive.

Comment: this is an amazing answer, it really helps clear things up for me. my 'intent' is just to learn map/reduce/filter to a degree that i end up selecting them in future problem-solving sessions, this was just a refactor of some existing code. 



i really appreciate your thoughtful response!

Answer (score 0):

```
dotArr.map(itemI => {
  const closestTarget = dotArr.reduce((currentMax, itemJ) => {
    if(currentMax === null){
       const targetDistance = findTarget(itemI, itemJ)}
       if(targetDistance !== null){
         return {item:itemJ, distance:targetDistance};
       }
       return null;
    }
    const newDistance = findTarget(itemI, itemJ);
    if((currentMax.distance - newDistance) < 0){ //No need to check if it is the same item, because distance is 0
      return {item:itemJ, distance: newDistance};
    }
    return sum;
  }, null);
  itemI.tgt = closestTarget.item;
  return itemI;
}
```

After constructing this example, i found that you are using a very complex example to figure out how map works.

`Array.map` is typically used for one value, so we can use it for `[i]`, then we need to iterate all the other values in the array using `[j]`, but we can't do this with map, because we only care about the closest `[j]`, so we can use `Array.reduce` which also is an accumulator like `Array.map`, but the end result is whatever you want it to be, while the end result of `Array.map` always is an array of same length.

What my `reduce` function does is that it iterates through the entire list, similar to `[j]`. I initialize the `currentMax` as `null`, so when `j==0` then `currentMax===null`, Then i figure out what state `[j]` is compared to `[i]`. The return statements is what `currentMax` will be equal to in `[j+1]`

When i finally found the closest target, i can just add it so `itemI.tgt` and i have to return it, so that the new map knows what the `item` looks like at the current `index`.

Without looking at `Array.map` this is how i imagine it is implemented

```
function myMap(inputArray, callback){
  const newArray = [];
  for(let i=0;i<inputArray.length;i++){
    newArray.push(callback(inputArray[i], i, inputArray));  
  }
  return newArray;
}
```

So this is why you always need to write return

Comment: The point made in the OP is that the poster understood the simple examples but couldn't figure out how to apply them to real-world situations like this one.

Comment: @ScottSauyet you are right. My first example covers it well, should focus on being a better proof reader

Answer (score -1):

I think in this instance you want to use `reduce` and NOT `map`.

`reduce` can allow you to "Reduce" an array of items to a single item.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

example

```
let largestThing = arrayOfThings.reduce(function (largest, nextItem) {
    if (largest == null) {
        return nextItem;
    }
    if (largest.prop > nextItem.prop){
        return largest;
    }
    return nextItem;
}, null);
```

`null` as the parameter of the callback is the starting "largest" in the callback.